# swift refreshcontrol, endRefreshing not working

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uirefreshcontrol

I'm having hard time to end the pull to refresh feature.

Even if I call the endRefreshing() on refershControl, the spinner stays there.  The tableview is refreshed properly though.

Here is my swift code :

```
@IBAction func refereshInvoked() {
    refresh_data()
    self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
}
```

Since I'm pretty new with Swift and Cocoa, I'm probably doing something wrong.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Do you actually set the refresh control? 
Put a break point in the code under refreshInvoked, then check that self.refreshControl is not NULL/nil.

Performing endRefreshing method on a nil object would compile but obviously nothing would happen. If it is nil then you need to create the refresh control object on viewdidload.

Comment: In Swift, a non-optional variable (such as `self.refreshControl`, note the missing `?` suffix) cannot be nil.